# Tom has been wanting a computer for two years

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

> Tom has been wanting a computer for two years. His dad has now decided to buy one for him next week.

Can I change the first sentence to

> 1. Tom has wanted a computer for two years.

or

> 2. Tom has often wanted a computer for two years.

or

> 3. Tom has always wanted a computer for two years.

Comment: Options 2 and 3 aren't idiomatic, but I'm not sure exactly how to explain what it is about the implications of ***often*** and ***always*** that prevent them from being used in the same construction as ***for** [some duration of time stretching back into the past]*. There's no such problem with at least *some* other adverbs - for example *He has **secretly** wanted a PC for two years*.

Comment: Thank you. Does option 1 change the original meaning?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - If you switch the order it becomes idiomatic.  *For [the past/last] two years Tom has often wanted a computer.*  It sounds even better with past/last.  It does not work with *always* because *always* doesn't work with a defined time frame.  *Always* is its own time frame.  Expressed over a time frame *always* becomes *constantly*.

Comment: @EllieK: I suppose different people might have different opinions here, but I personally don't find OP's or your examples remotely idiomatic. I might just about go along with ***often*** or ***always*** if the other adverbial element used a different preposition *(**during, over, throughout**),* as well as ***the past / last***, but it would have to be in an unusual context where I either needed to stress the "continually" aspect *(**always**)*, or call attention to the somewhat "sporadic" nature of his desires *(**often**)*. It's not a very natural usage, though.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes.
2. No. *Often* implies that the thought only occurred to him occasionally, so it would have to be *during the past two years.*
3. No. If you say *I've always wanted X*, obviously it doesn't mean literally all your life, but for a very long time - so you wouldn't say it with a definite time period.

Comment: *Often implies that the thought only occurred to him occasionally?* "Often" is much more frequent than "occasioally", in my opinion.

Comment: I was trying to make the distinction between _he has wanted one for 2 years_ (which means (not literally) that he has spent the whole time wishing he had one) and _he has often wanted one_ (the thought has occurred to him from time to time "A computer would be useful for this".)